# Перегрузка оператора[] C++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

```
class LinkedList{
public:
    int* operator[](const int i)
        {
            int *p = new int(i);
            return p;
        }
};
int main()
{
LinkedList *ptr = new LinkedList();
int* p = ptr[0];
}
```

Не компилируется, выдает ошибку:
Невозможно преобразовать сущность LinkedList в int, где я неправильно перегружаю оператор?

Comment: @AnT, поправил код, перегрузка всё равно не работает. Просто вопрос в том, что как бы я не перегружал оператор [], его использование всё равно указывает на экземпляр класса, а перегрузку даже отладка просто пропускает.

Comment: Зачем вы в `main` делаете `LinkedList *ptr = new LinkedList();`? Почему не просто `LinkedList my_list;`?

Comment: Все неправильно - гляньте https://www.pvsm.ru/programmirovanie/181616

Comment: Извините, но Вы ведь ничего не поправили. Внутри Вашего класса вы должны хранить какой-то массив, чтобы можно было применять этот оператор к его элементам. В случае же с LinkedList-ом это все выглядит в корне иначе. Прочтите сперва, как выглядит эта структура данных, чтобы Вам было понятнее, куда двигаться дальше. [вот](https://gist.github.com/charlierm/5691020)

Comment: @Lex Marchenko: Человек привел **синтетический пример** - просто набросок кода, дистиллированный эксперимент со свойствами языка. Не надо рассказывать ему, что он "должен хранить" внутри класса. Это дело десятое.

Comment: @AnT, безусловно, не осмелюсь с Вами спорить, но то, о чем сказал я, может добавить ему ясности, если он экспериментирует с языком:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оператор `[]` вы перегружали для типа `LinkedList`. Переменная `ptr` имеет тип `LinkedList *` и выражение `ptr[0]` применяет `[]` к типу `LinkedList *`. `LinkedList` и `LinkedList *` - два разных типа.

В `ptr[0]` будет использоваться *встроенный* оператор `[]`, который не имеет никакого отношения к вашему перегруженному оператору `[]`.

Ваш перегруженный `[]` будет использоваться, например, в выражении `(*ptr)[0]`.

Comment: но все же утечка памяти будет...

Answer (score 0):

Вы ведь просто передаете `int i` и пытаетесь вернуть это же `i`, которое является типом `int`, а не указателем на int (`int*`), как указано в Вашем операторе.
Перегрузка такого оператора выглядит примерно так.

```
ReturnType& operator[](int index) const 
{
    return someArray[index];
}
```

*При этом в Вашей структуре данных должно находится что-то, для чего вы будете применять вышеуказанный оператор